# Use a one-dimensional array, explode it, and create a multidimensional-array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
 (
  [0] => john.smith@domain.com:John
  [1] => jane.doe@domain.com:Jane
)
```

As you can see, it's user'semail and user's name, seperated by a colon.

I want to create a multi dimensional array, that explodes the colon, and then will create a multi dimensional array that would look more like

```
Array
 (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [user_email] => john.smith@domain.com
        [user_name] => John
    )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [user_email] => jane.doe@domain.com
        [user_name] => Jane
    )

)
```

Comment: `foreach` loop, `explode` on colon, give it a go, im sure you can do it :-)

Comment: I know foreach and explode will work. But then how would I go about creating a new array?

Comment: $new[counter\key][user_email]=exploded part 0; $new[counter\key][user_name]=exploded part 1;

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
<?php

$data = [
    "john.smith@domain.com:John",
    "jane.doe@domain.com:Jane"
];

function customArray($data){
    $final = [];
    $i = 0;

    foreach($data as $k => $v){
        $splitted = explode(":",$v);
        $final[$i]['user_email'] = $splitted[0];
        $final[$i]['user_name']  = $splitted[1];
        $i++;
    }

    return $final;
}

print_r(customArray($data));
```

See the results [here](https://3v4l.org/lPeMS).
Basically what I do above is

- iterate over the array,
- explode the value by the delimiter `:`,
- index them within the iteration using the same `[$i]` so that the new key/value is paired correctly per original array element.

Do properly name things though, I'm just giving an example :-)

Comment: yeah right, I'll edit and add a bit more explanation in a bit

Comment: @joseph-parker if you don't understand any part of it, feel free to ask and also, welcome to SO!

Comment: you dont need the $i, you could just use the original array keys

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the every element of source array and save it in a new array like below. Finally, you will be getting the desired format in $result array.

```
$source_array = array("john.smith@domain.com:John","jane.doe@domain.com:Jane");
foreach($name_email_array as $key => $value){
        $name_email = explode(":",$value);
        $result[$key]['user_email'] = $name_email[0];
        $result[$key]['user_name']  = $name_email[1];
    }
```